# Why is my button surrounded by a red border from where comes this border?

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx

I'm using a button on my main menu created by `texturepacker.jar` as button.pack file with a `PNG` , the problem in my PNG button there is no red border but when i run the program i see the button surrounded by a 1 pixel red border that I can't seem to find from where comes !

here is the button in the run time :

[image]

and this is the code who generate the button :

```
@Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(3, 2, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        stage.act(delta);
        stage.draw();
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
        stage = new Stage();

        atlas = new TextureAtlas("gui/button.pack");
        skin = new Skin(atlas);


        table = new Table(skin);
        table.setBounds(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());

        black = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("font/black.fnt"), false);

        TextButtonStyle textButtonStyle = new TextButtonStyle();
        textButtonStyle.up = skin.getDrawable("button_up");
        textButtonStyle.down = skin.getDrawable("button_pressed");
        textButtonStyle.pressedOffsetX = 1;
        textButtonStyle.pressedOffsetY = -1;
        textButtonStyle.font = black;

        buttonExit = new TextButton("EXIT", textButtonStyle);
        buttonExit.pad(20);

        table.add(buttonExit);
        table.debug();
        stage.addActor(table);

    }
```

any help on how to remove this red border?

Comment: firebug with Java desktop application ? :) how ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The border is there due to `table.debug();`. Remove this and the red border should disappear.

The scene2d debugging functionality should help to show how a Table will layout the cells and actors within. It can also help with event handling to show the bounds of arbitrary actors for mouse-over or click events.

In the past it was necessary to have a seperate `drawDebug()` call, but this has been changed and is now integrated into `stage.draw();` when debugging has been enabled.